# Temporary disable function keys in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

I want to be able to temporary disable Ctrl / Alt / F1-F12 keys on Windows 7 computer.

So that only letters and numbers keys could be pressed.

Is there a tool that allows to do that quickly and then easily revert it back?

Comment: You could map those keys to a program that does nothing, like `wscript //b`. Might affect focus / active window though...

Comment: Install a new keyboard driver and use its configuration parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I thought this question is a simple software recommendation question. How wrong I was.

Google only knows [KidKeyLock](http://www.100dof.com/products/kid-key-lock) which blocks some keys.

[image]

There seems to be a lack of tools to block custom keyboard keys and key combinations.
Even [Alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/kidkeylock/) doesn't know any similar software

Comment: While KidKeyLock is trying to install bunch of adware with it (and does not block custom keyboard keys), it does the "minimum required" job for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could use an [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script to setup something like this:

```
RCtrl::return    ; disables Right Contrl key
LCtrl::return
RShift::return
LShift::return
RAlt::return
LAlt::return
F1::return
F2::return
...
```

Once running you can click the icon in the system tray and click 'Suspend Hotkeys' to turn it off.

PS: editing the script to test it was quite difficult once I turned off the shift and control keys... :)

Comment: Yes, checked  AutoHotKey website - but I'd rather prefer something pre-configured, sort of single-click utility

Comment: 1) Install AHK. 2) Save the text above as DisableKeys.ahk 3) double click it 4) ???  5) Profit!

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a built-in [scancode mapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) facility if you do not want to use 3rd-party tools.

Run the following command as Administrator then reboot the PC to disable F1-F12 keys:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /t "REG_BINARY" /d "00000000000000000D00000000003B0000003C0000003D0000003E0000003F000000400000004100000042000000430000004400000057000000580000000000" /f
```

To restore the default mapping (also run as Administrator then reboot):

```
REG DELETE "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /f
```